# Spark not working with error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path"

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apache-spark, snappy

I am using the CDH4 build of Spark 1.2.0 to submit a jar of Scala code built using `sbt assembly`.

Both spark shell and spark submit are failing with below error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
```

Though I have included snappy as a dependency in build.sbt as below, and it gets downloaded too.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Spark dependency
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.0.5.4"
)
```

Please suggest, what is the issue and appropriate resolution.

Here is the spark-submit command

./spark-submit --class org.cmls.SparkExamples.Spark_First  /home/varun/SPARK/spark-1.2.0/assembly/target/scala-2.11/my-project-assembly.jar

Comment: Is snappy-java :
- on your executors ? (do you use `--jars` with `spark-submit` ?)
- on your classpath ? (how do you build your `SparkConfig`)

Comment: Please include your `spark-submit` command in the question.

Comment: I am using a downloaded,  pre-built package , spark-1.2.0-bin-cdh4.